# How to embed and use polarSSL into Android project?

Tags: android, ios, ssl, tcp, polarssl

Currently, I'm trying to use PolarSSL to make a SSL connection between Android and iOS devices.

I'm able to embed it into iOS project using this library 
https://github.com/x2on/PolarSSL-for-iOS

However, I cannot find any tutorial or example for Android.

Is there anyone experiment this ?

Thanks a lot for any responses.

Best regards.

Comment: Android already has ssl support. The ssl support in Android should be able to talk to another client/host with whatever library you are using as long as they use the same protocols and encryption schemes. Do you have a good reason for using PolorSSL? My guess any advantage you have with using a c ssl library such as PolarSSL on Android will come with the complexity of building the C library for Android. I had no issues working with SSL in Java on Android.